# Install Mysql Gem in ROR on windows 7 machine

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I tried installing `mysql2` gem but I see this Error.

```
Using --with-mysql-dir=C:/mysql-connector
-----
checking for main() in -llibmysql... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby
        --with-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/
        --with-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
        --with-libmysqllib
        --without-libmysqllib


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.14 for inspec
Results logged to C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.14/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

I have tried copying `llibmysql.dll` file to `Ruby/bin` and `Ruby/lib` folders and tried I don't see success.

Please let me know if someone has faced this issue (I guess this is specific to Windows 7 + ROR + Mysql)

Comment: I work on windows and i gave up using rails (or django) on it a long time ago. I use a Virtual machine with a Linux to run my dev environnements. I strongly advise you to do the same, as you will encounter a lot of errors for a lot of external libraries on Windows.

Comment: I accept ROR on Windows should be the worst thing to do. I'll plan to switch to Linux soon..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
gem install mysql2 -- '--with-mysql-lib="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\lib" --with-mysql-include="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\include"'


Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql2-0.3.14
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mysql2-0.3.14...
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Installing RDoc documentation for mysql2-0.3.14...
```